# Unable to customize logo in Plone subsites with INavigationRoot

Tags: plone, plone-4.x

I ran into a problem after activating Dexterity-based Plone Default Types in Plone 4.3.3.  I had a number of subsites (folders with the INavigationRoot interface activated.)  Each of these subsites has a custom logo, which is stored as `logo.png` in each folder that serves as navigation root.  It was working just fine, until I activated Dexterity-based Plone default types.  At that point, all of the custom logos were replaced by the one shown on the base Plone site.

As I investigated the problem, I noticed in the rendered HTML that the subsite logo was the absolute URL.  I was expecting an unqualified reference to logo.png, which would be found in the current folder OR the default location of `portal_skins/custom`.

Logo is defined in the properties of the Sunburst theme, located at  `buildout_cache/plonetheme.sunburst-1.4.6-py2.7.egg/plonetheme/sunburst/skins/sunburst_styles/base_properties.props`

```
logoName:string=logo.png
```

`logoName` is used by `LogoViewlet` as defined in `buildout_cache/plone.app.layout-2.3.12-py2.7.egg/plone/app/layout/viewlets/common.py`

For whatever reason, custom logos are being ignored, with subsites rendering the base logo instead.

Crude solution: edit `buildout-cache/eggs/plone.app.layout-2.3.11-py2.7.egg/plone/app/layout/viewlets/logo.pt`

Change:

```
    <img src="logo.jpg" alt=""
    tal:replace="structure view/logo_tag" /></a>
```

To:

```
    <img src="logo.png" alt=""  /></a>
```

This ignores skin properties, hard-coding the logo as `logo.png` throughout all Plone sites and subsites on the server.  All are working again.

Obviously I have a workaround solution for the problem, but what is the "proper" fix?

Comment: Why this question deserves down votes?

Comment: Like Mathias I wonder why this was downvoted. Moderators, please be aware that Plone-users are directed to SO from plone.org/support.

Comment: @IdaEbkes It's a question about programming, with code example and a (not so good) solution. That's why he is asking :-) imho it's also a good question with enough context to answer it.

Comment: @Mathias Yeah, I actually was agreeing with you, that there shouldn't be a reason to downvote :)

Comment: It is probably the same psycho who hangs out at #plone on irc who downvoted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A proper fix would be to register a new logo viewlet, which handles your use case.

- If you are on the Plone-root it should use the logo defined in the properties.
- If you are in a part of the site with a NavigationRoot use the logo directy below the navigation root.

But before you start developing...

[`ftw.subsite`](https://github.com/4teamwork/ftw.subsite/blob/1dca601c197120d165edba3082e28445ec2d65fb/ftw/subsite/viewlets/subsitelogoviewlet.py) as a Plone package, which does exactly what you want.

- You can upload a new logo for each subsite (Field on content).
- You can define new CSS for each subsite (Field on content).
- It's also possible to serve a subsite in a different language.
- The subsite is also a NavigationRoot.
- A subsite has his own ContactForm.
- More...

**Explanation, why your custom logos were ignored**

[`view/logo_tag`](https://github.com/plone/plone.app.layout/blob/6a5ec16543f04f2273a480bb4a9a83bf5c590b31/plone/app/layout/viewlets/common.py#L188) gets the portal root, which is the plone root, not the navigation root. 
Then it tries to get the logo configured in base_properties (or 'logo.png' as fallback) relative to the plone root.
That's why you cannot simply add a logon.png to a folder with NavigationRoot.

**Do not use relative paths for resources**

It's considered a bad idea to use relative paths for resources, this way the browser cannot cache the logo. The browser has to load it always new, because it has a different path.

Comment: @David Cavanaugh If you find this answer useful, please accept or add comments, so we can find a suitable solution for you!

Comment: cool, your welcome :-) please accept the answer. this is important for others who facing the same problem.